# strange behavior of == in Java

Tags: java, string, boolean, equals

I observed a strange behavior `==` operator in java. I am trying to print the out put as follows

```
String str1 = "Rajesh";
String str2 = "Rajesh";
System.out.println("Using equals() str1 and str2 Equals :"
            + str1.equals(str2));
System.out.println("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" 
            + str1 == str2);
```

The first SOP statement printing

> Using equals() str1 and str2 Equals :true

and the next SOP printing only false .

I tried compiling in both eclipse and Net Beans but result is the same .
I am so confused why

> Using == str1 and str2 Equals :

is not printing

Help me out in this

Thanks in advance,

Raj

Comment: Did you try encapsulating the condition in parenthesis? It's possible the first condition is added to your string then evaluated with str2.

Comment: `"Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + str1 == str2` will be the equivalent of `"Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + "Rajesh" == "Rajesh"`. Because `+` has a higher precedence than `==` (`2 + 2 == 4`), we'll have the equivalent of `"Using == str1 and str2 Equals :Rajesh" == "Rajesh"`, which will be `false`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: @Josh reat comment thanks you so munch

Comment: When you don't use any parentheses, the `==` operator is evaluated last.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it's the same as `("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + str1) == str2` and this is false, of course. Expression is parsed from left to right and so at first it concatenates `"Using == str1 and str2 Equals :"` and `str1`, then applies `==` operator.

Answer (score 7):

See http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php for a table of operator precedence in Java.

The + operator is higher precedence than the == operator.

So, in effect, your code is equivalent to the following:

```
System.out.println( ("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + str1) == str2);
```

Note the placement of the parentheses that I added.  It evaluates to this:

```
System.out.println( (str_x + str1) == str2);
```

And then to this:

```
System.out.println( str_y == str2 );
```

And then to this:

```
System.out.println( false );
```

In order to get the result you want, you must use parentheses to specify that you want the == operator to be resolved BEFORE the + operator:

```
System.out.println( "Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + (str1 == str2));
```

Notice the new placement of the parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Because + has higher priority compare to = and if you use bracket(str1 == str2) then 
 this result give true because highest priority is (.
So First it checks bracket inside data.

```
String str1 = "Rajesh";
        String str2 = "Rajesh";
        System.out.println("Using equals() str1 and str2 Equals :"
                + str1.equals(str2));
        System.out.println("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" 
                + (str1 == str2));
```

Output:

```
Using equals() str1 and str2 Equals :true
Using == str1 and str2 Equals :true
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an order of operations thing? Try:

```
System.out.println("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + (str1 == str2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding it with () like this:

```
System.out.println("Using == str1 and str2 Equals :" + (str1 == str2));
```

Comment: It works fine and prints this: `Using == str1 and str2 Equals :true`. The explain is given by @Ademiban

Answer (score 0):

equals method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object.Follwoing is the Object class implementation of equals method.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
    }
```

In String class this method has overridden as following.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

And if you use == operator it just check both references are having same object. Similar to the Object class equals method.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that you cannot compare strings in Java using `==`.

In C++ or C# (or other languages supporting operator redefinition), you can overwrite the `==` operator to provide that functionality. Java does not support that.

Comment: You mean overload, not overwrite (or override). And yes, you *can* compare string references using `==` in Java. It will compare the references, not the objects, but that would work fine in this particular case, if it had been used correctly.

Comment: Yes, I meant overload. And thanks for pointing on that reference thing. I just did not know that.

Answer (score -1):

`str1.equals(str2)` returns `true` because the `equals()` function compares the content of the string variables, where as `==` operator compares the instances. Since `str1` and `str2` are two differences of instances of `String` class, it returns `false`

Comment: Here, `str1` and `str2` will be identical references to the same string though, due to the way the language handles compile-time string constants.

Answer (score -1):

In Java `==` operator matches the two objects i.e their address while `.equals()`  method mathces the values of both objects, thats why you are getting `true` for `equals()` and `false` for `==` as both are different objects.

Answer (score -2):

`==` can only be used to compare primitive datatypes. To compare objects you need to use `equals` method. Using a `==` operator on objects actually compares there addresses instead of values.

Comment: Well, it compares the values - but those values are references. It's incorrect to say that `==` *can only be used to compare primitive datatypes* when it can also be used to test for reference equality. In this case, as we're dealing with two occurrences of the same string constant, `==` would work fine - if it were being used correctly.

Comment: Bearing in mind that the vast majority of objects out there do not override equals and simply return the result of ==.  It's a fairly common mistake I see for people to just assume "I used .equals so this will work right."